# google.maps.event.trigger

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Struggling hours to get google maps working. When click on the 2nd tab, the map is only displaying 30%. It's broken. I'm using event trigger to reload the map.

Any solutions to get my map displayed fully??????

Comment: did you fix this? i found a solution

Answer (score 0):

First I noticed that you have some spots saying Demo.map and others saying demo.map   Be sure to keep consistant capitalization throughout code to avoid any errors. Also you could place the variable declaration before the jQuery statements to ensure less errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the right idea, but you've named your map Demo.Map and you're triggering a resize on demo.map.

demo.map !== Demo.map

EDIT: Response to Comment

Looking over the jQuery UI tabs API (http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show) - the name of the event you should be calling is active, not show, so the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        show: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.index == -1) {
                google.maps.event.trigger(Demo.map, "resize");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Should look like this (get rid of the if statement - the resize event is lightweight and doesn't matter if you call it when unnecessary):

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(e, ui) {                                
         google.maps.event.trigger(Demo.map, "resize");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Open your JavaScript console when visiting the page - it tells you exactly what the problem is. You didn't the } belonging to the if statement that you removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        show: function(e, ui) {                                
         google.maps.event.trigger(Demo.map, "resize");   
        }
    });
});
```